# Netbook Windows 7 recovery

Tags: windows-7, grub, mbr

I have an Asus 1005PE netbook which I installed Ubuntu on as a second partition a while back. Its primary partition is Windows 7 Starter. I've now upgraded to a bigger laptop and am selling this netbook, so wish to restore it back to its factory state.

From the Grub menu, I choose 'Windows Recovery Environment' (as the netbook came with a recovery partition). This stepped me through restoring (although it did seem to be very quick doing this). Then it took me back to the grub menu. Now when I chose the Windows 7 option - it says:

```
error: no such device: 82E080B4E080B049.
error: no such disk.
```

Ubuntu does still successfully boot though.

In grub, if I go to the grub command prompt and do an "ls -l", then it lists the devices. If I then change the Windows 7 entry to hd0,msdos1 and 90B85A1DB85A0260 based on the results the ls command gave - then when I try to boot using those parameters it says "BOOTMGR is missing".

Note that this is a netbook, so doesn't have a cdrom drive.

I'm not really sure what my next course of action should be (I'm worried about losing the recovery information). The netbook has already been sold on eBay, so I really need to sort this out as soon as possible.

Thank you for any help with this,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only seen a few Asus netbook models, but they all had the option to press F9 immediately after turning it on. This would take you to a factory restore option.

Comment: It does have an F9 option in the POST, and when I press it it says "Image recovery has been selected", but then it goes to the Grub menu still. I'm guessing this would have just gone to the "Windows Recovery Environment" partition that I went to initially from the grub menu.

Comment: Actually, after doing the F9 thing and then choosing the Windows Recovery Environment - it seems to be doing much more than it did when I just choose Windows Recovery Environment without the F9! It's now got a recovery progress bar! Fingers crossed ...

Comment: Sorted! Once that recovery finished, I had to alter the grub config as described in my initial post so that it would boot into the recovered windows 7 installation. Then I used the MBRWizard CLI to write the MBR to the Win7 default. Then I deleted the Ubuntu partition and resized the Win7 one to fill the empty space. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You did way more work than I did, but glad you got it working.